# JS Parameter & Arguments

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, console.log

Please help me with the exercises, for some reason, my code isn't working and it won't allow it to run successfully.

```
// Exercise One: 
// Step One: Create a function called 'parametersExercise'. 
// Step Two: This function will need to take two parameters, call them 'param1' and 'param2'
// Step Three: The function should console log the second parameter.


// DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ON THE NEXT FOUR LINES!
function exerciseTwo(){
  function sayMyName(parameter1){
    console.log(parameter1);
  }


// Continue below this line:
```

**Is this code below accurate?

```
 function parametersExercise(param1, param2){

 console.log(param2);
 }



// Exercise Two:
// Step One create a variable called 'myName' and assign it the a string of your name.
// Step Two: Call the function called "sayMyName",passing the 'myName' variable as it's only argument.
// NOTE: You do NOT need to create the function (sayMyName), doing so will break the test. 
//       It has been created for you.
let myName = "Juell";
sayMyName(myName);

console.log();

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Your function already seems to answer your 3 requirements

Comment: I think you are not able to understand the exercise properly.

Comment: @robertlee-I apologize, I had a formatting issue, I am asking what is wrong with the code within the two exercise questions I have listed? For some reason the code will not run successfully. I am learning arguments and parameters with console.log, but this exercise is quite challenging for me.

Comment: What do you mean by that it won't run successfully? What are you expecting it to do? What do you actually get?

Comment: I am expecting the first exercise to console log the second parameter when I run it, there is a fail message that pops up stating expected 'undefined' to be a function. @Newbyte

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and get rid of the last console.log and change the let to var.  so, here is the part you do:

var myName = "YourName";
sayMyName(myName);

Comment: Share your complete code or working fiddle link. Thanks